# Cisco ASA: will 7.2 -> 8.2 upgrade break ipsec-ra functionality?

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, anyconnect

We have a Cisco ASA 5505 running version 7.2.  The current config includes both a site-to-site VPN (ipsec-l2l) and a remote access VPN where users connect using the Cisco VPN client 5.0.06 (ipsec-ra).

Because the cisco VPN client lacks support for Windows 7, 64 bit OSes and SBL on Vista we need to upgrade to the AnyConnect client, which means the ASA needs to be upgraded to version 8.X.

I have two questions about this upgrade (being asked separately)

1)  Will upgrading to version 8.2 break the existing ipsec-ra VPN configuration, and require all clients to upgrade to Anyconnect immediately or will the Cisco VPN client 5.0.06 software continue to work with the upgraded ASA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPSEC access using the Cisco VPN Client will still work after the upgrade.
To be able to use AnyConnect you will need to add some extra configuration.

Comment: Confirmed by upgrading. :-)